# Windowed writing in rasterio?

Tags: python, rasterio

I have two large datasets, `RP1` and `RP2`. I would like to subtract one from the other, however the datasets are extremely large and so exit out with a `MemoryError` when I try a direct read:

```
RP1 = rasterio.open(big_file_path)
RP1 = RP1.read(1, masked=True)

RP1 = RP1_dataset.read(1, masked=True)
```

> File "rasterio_io.pyx", line 348, in
>
> rasterio._io.DatasetReaderBase.read MemoryError

Therefore I have tried to resort to windowed reading and writing as explained by the `rasterio` [docs](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/windowed-rw.html). I wrote the following script:

```
import numpy
import rasterio


image = numpy.ones((150, 250), dtype=rasterio.ubyte) * 127
RP1_filename = r'RP1.tif'
RP2_filename = r'RP2.tif'

RP2 = rasterio.open(RP2_filename)
profile = RP2.profile
with rasterio.open(RP1_filename) as RP1:
    for block_index, window in RP1.block_windows(1):
        RP1_block = RP1.read(window=window,masked = True)
        RP2_block = RP2.read(window=window, masked = True)
        result_block = RP2_block - RP1_block
        print(result_block.shape)

RP2.close()
```

Since `RP1` and `RP2` have the same window schema I took the liberty of indexing into `RP2` by the current `RP1` block index. This seems to work fine and the `result_block` variable contains a masked array as expected.

The problem is I don't know how to collect all these arrays properly such that I can write a new output raster with the result values.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly write the result blocks to the big result tiff file via windowed writing.

```
import rasterio

src_RP1 = rasterio.open(r'RP1_filename.tif')
src_RP2 = rasterio.open(r'RP2_filename.tif')

out_profile = src_RP1.profile.copy()
dst = rasterio.open(r'result.tif', 'w', **out_profile)

for block_index, window in src_RP1.block_windows(1):
    RP1_block = src_RP1.read(window=window, masked=True)
    RP2_block = src_RP2.read(window=window, masked=True)

    result_block = RP2_block - RP1_block
    dst.write(result_block, window=window)

src_RP1.close()
src_RP2.close()
dst.close()
```

If indeed you want to assemble one big results array in memory you would have to initialize an empty array with the dimensions of RP1 and iteratively assign the block arrays to the respective rows/columns (you can get these from the window).