# Downloading the global SoilGrids data using Python

Tags: python, soilgrids

I would like to use Python to download a selection of layers from SoilGrids (global extent) for use in ecological modelling. I would like them to be GeoTIFFs, so using GDAL translate during download would be ideal.

However when using the example code from https://git.wur.nl/isric/soilgrids/soilgrids.notebooks/-/blob/master/markdown/webdav_from_Python.md and specifically the following (slightly modified):

```
location = “https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/clay/clay_0-5cm_mean.vrt”

sg_url = f"/vsicurl?max_retry=3&retry_delay=1&list_dir=no&url={location}"
 
kwargs = {'format': 'GTiff', 'creationOptions': ["TILED=YES", "COMPRESS=DEFLATE", "PREDICTOR=2", "BIGTIFF=YES"]}
 
ds = gdal.Translate(os.path.join(os.getcwd()+'\Data\clay_0-5cm_mean_igh_py.tif'),
                    sg_url, **kwargs)
```

I get this error:

> ERROR 4: `/vsicurl?max_retry=3&retry_delay=1&list_dir=no&url=https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/clay./clay_0-5cm_mean/tileSG-000-023/tileSG-000-023_3-1.tif' not recognized as a supported file format.

Since I can download a tile when `location = https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/clay/clay_0-5cm_mean/tileSG-000-020/tileSG-000-020_3-1.tif`, I assume it is something to do with incorrectly interpreting the vrt file structure? The ‘./’ in the middle of the path name may be the issue?

I’m using Python 3.7.4 and gdal 2.3.3. I have tried updating these to see if it’s a version problem and I have just gone around in circles getting nowhere with my Anaconda installation (it won’t update past these two versions – yes I have uninstalled everything and started afresh).

Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes gdal error are not describing accurately the problem encountered

I slightly modified your code by using pathlib for file naming and creating the output folder (data). I also decided to split the url creation to have additional control on it and finally I used LZW as a compression system:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from osgeo import gdal

# the destination file 
data = Path.cwd()/'data'
data.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
dst = str(data/'clay_0-5cm_mean_igh_py.tif')

# create the downloading url in 3 steps
location = 'https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data'
sg_url = f'/vsicurl?max_retry=3&retry_delay=1&list_dir=no&url={location}'
src = sg_url + '/clay/clay_0-5cm_mean.vrt'
 
kwargs = {'format': 'GTiff', 'creationOptions': ["TILED=YES", "COMPRESS=LZW", "PREDICTOR=2", "BIGTIFF=YES"]}
 
ds = gdal.Translate(dst, src, **kwargs)
```

It worked from my side like a charm.

#### PS

I used `gdal` because you were specifically asking for it but in the future for Python image manipulation I suggest you have a look at [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that provide a more pythonic way of dealing with datasets (`with` statement, numpy array, pathlib path ...etc).

Comment: How do we get a subset of data directly in gdal.Translate using -projwin as in this tutorial? I get a -srcwin with negative height using these coords:`(-8793568.516, 4893742.131, -8781155.092, 4903568.017)`

https://git.wur.nl/isric/soilgrids/soilgrids.notebooks/-/blob/master/markdown/webdav_from_Python.md

Comment: Hi @Clousseau and welcome to StackExchange. This is not a Forum site but a Q&A system. New questions should not be asked in the comment section but in a new thread. see https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Some extra information, tile `tileSG-000-020_3-1.tif` is located on Alasca, would not be surprised if this cases some projection problem.

In any case the code below is based on [windowed-writing-in-rasterio](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299664/windowed-writing-in-rasterio) and [read-and-then-write-rasterio-geotiff-file-without-loading-all-data-into-memory](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/368874/read-and-then-write-rasterio-geotiff-file-without-loading-all-data-into-memory) and it implements `rasterio` Window R/W to avoid overloading memory with content but also copies the tags containing soilgrids information (how the raster was created).

```
from pathlib import Path
import rasterio

# the destination file 
data = Path.cwd() / 'data'
data.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
dst = str(data/'clay_0-5cm_mean_igh_py.tif')

# create the downloading url in 3 steps
sg_layer = 'clay/clay_0-5cm_mean.vrt'
location = f'https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/{sg_layer}'
sg_url = f'/vsicurl?max_retry=3&retry_delay=1&list_dir=no&url={location}'

with rasterio.open(sg_url) as src:
    
    kwds = src.profile
    tags = src.tags() # Add soilgrids tags with creation info.
    kwds['driver'] = 'GTiff'
    kwds['tiled'] = True
    kwds['compress'] = 'deflate' # lzw or deflate
    kwds['dtype']: 'int16' # soilgrids datatype
    kwds['nodata'] = -32768 # default nodata

    with rasterio.open(dst, 'w', **kwds) as dst:
        for ji, window in src.block_windows(1):
            dst.update_tags(**tags)
            dst.write(src.read(window=window), window=window)
```

It will slowly but steady download soilgrids data without major resource consumption.

Comment: Thanks to both Pierrick and Jorge for taking a look at my problem.

Comment: I am still having problems, even with your modifications:  
CPLE_OpenFailedError         Traceback (most recent call last)
rasterio\_io.pyx in rasterio._io.DatasetReaderBase._read()
rasterio\shim_rasterioex.pxi in rasterio._shim.io_multi_band()
rasterio\_err.pyx in rasterio._err.exc_wrap_int()

CPLE_OpenFailedError: '/vsicurl?max_retry=3&retry_delay=1&list_dir=no&url=https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/clay\./clay_0-5cm_mean/tileSG-000-020/tileSG-000-020_3-4.tif' not recognized as a supported file format.

Comment: Am I missing something in my python setup that would allow me to read vrt files?

Comment: Is my version working ? if that's the case, you may have a conflict between your gdal and your rasterio installation.

Comment: @PierrickRambaud Yes, your version is working very well kudos

Comment: oh my question was more for [@jen](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/190335/jen) that is still experiencing problems, have a look to the rasterio doc for troubleshouting: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/switch.html

Comment: @Jen Could you try to download the tile directally from here:

https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/clay/clay_0-5cm_mean/tileSG-000-020/

And try to open with your GDAL installation. It could be that your install has some problem with the tiff library

Comment: I am still getting the same error - something in my gdal cannot read the vrt file properly, and I get the same error when using the rasterio option from Jorge. I can download an individual geotiff and open it with gdal without a problem - so it's something with the vrt. There's a "\." in the url path for an individual geotiff in the error I get - should that "\." even there? The vrt has:  "<SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">./clay_0-5cm_mean/tileSG-018-027/tileSG-018-027_2-4.tif</SourceFilename>" but then a backslash comes from somewhere - why? how? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: the source file is a `.vrt`, meaning that it does not embed any input but rather xml description of the tiff file to use. On the server side they are stored in `./clay_0-5cm_mean` that's normal and should have 0 influence on your download